# SetReadAccess error for new ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform, acl

I have the following code placed in my application class of an Android app of mine:

```
// Register ParseObject subclasses
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Results.class);

// Set up Parse
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(MyApplication.this);
Parse.initialize(MyApplication.this, PARSE_APP_KEY, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

This seems to work great whenever I have a fresh install of my app and I create new Results objects.  Now, if I update my app via the Play store, or install over it via Android Studio, I get the following error whenever new Results objects, or any other ParseObject or subclass thereof, are created:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id
```

Is this a bug with Parse?  I get the same results with the Offline Todo example.

Comment: This to me looks like the `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser()` doesn't allows for the ACL to be set - I am not sure why as I haven't used the automatic user functionality however

Comment: The strange thing is that everything works fine (ParseObjects get created with no ACL error) in the app until I either update it or overwrite the install with another dev version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure to save the current user.

```
// Register ParseObject subclasses
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Results.class);

// Set up Parse
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(MyApplication.this);
Parse.initialize(MyApplication.this, PARSE_APP_KEY, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground(); // <--- This Line
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

Not entirely sure about my syntax, I've only done it in Swift.

Comment: When I try that, I get a different error: `IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up. Call signUp first.`

My goal is to store parse data as an anonymous user until the user wants to signup.  Then allow saving to the cloud.

Comment: On my app, I don't call sign up and it works fine. Can you anonymously sign them up?

Comment: Nevermind, I spoke too soon.  I didn't fully uninstall the app before trying that code.  Now it seems to work if I install over a previous version.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

delete  the app from device, and install again. it should work.

here is my setup

```
    //Parser App Crash Report
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this); //THIS is to test only =>  throw new RuntimeException("Test Exception!");

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Initialise
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APP_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

then test with :

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.put("2", "2");
testObject.put("3", "3");
testObject.saveInBackground();
```