# quick start parse not working on android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm really new at using android studio and parse. I was making an app and using parse quick start to store data but whenever i run the app, the log cat shows this message.

> 02-21 09:32:58.440    2492-2492/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕
>   Generating report file for crash 02-21 09:32:58.560
>   2492-2492/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Retrieving logcat
>   output... 02-21 09:32:58.680    2492-2492/com.parse.starter
>   D/CrashReporting﹕ Retrieving logcat output... 02-21 09:32:58.690
>   2492-2492/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Retrieving logcat
>   output... 02-21 09:32:59.160    2492-2492/com.parse.starter
>   V/CrashReporting﹕ About to start ReportSenderWorker from
>   handleException 02-21 09:32:59.160    2492-2521/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Loading file
>   1424532778440-IllegalArgumentException-1.stacktrace 02-21 09:32:59.180
>   2492-2521/com.parse.starter I/CrashReporting﹕ Sending file
>   1424532778440-IllegalArgumentException-1.stacktrace 02-21 09:32:59.180
>   2492-2521/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Sending crash report to
>   Parse... 02-21 09:32:59.270    2492-2492/com.parse.starter
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 2492
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user
>   with null id
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id
>               at com.parse.ParseACL.setReadAccess(ParseACL.java:305)
>               at com.parse.ParseACL.getDefaultACL(ParseACL.java:59)
>               at com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:3365)
>               at com.parse.ParseObject.(ParseObject.java:175)
>               at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity.onCreate(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:16)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this so I can move on with my app? This is my code in parse application class:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      // Initialize Crash Reporting.
      ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

      // Enable Local Datastore.
      Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

      // Add your initialization code here
      Parse.initialize(this, "id", "key");
      ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
      ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
      // Optionally enable public read access.
      defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
      ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

and activity file

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881284/833647

Comment: its still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

I commented out the automaticUser() and ACL related code in ParseApplication.java and that fixed it.

```
//    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
//    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
//    Optionally enable public read access.
//    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
//    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Parse.initialize(this, "id", "key");` 
Add the corresponding keys to it and see if it works?

Comment: oh i ran it like that. i just didn't share the key of my project over here. The keys get compiled successfully but when i copy and paste the test object code, all these errors pop up in log cat and a window on emulator pops up and says parser project has stopped working

Answer (score 0):

You do need to add your id and key in the code as per other comment.
ALSO you need to add them in the Manifest....

But even then, it still crashes for me.