# setReadAccess for a user with a null ID. Parse Object

Tags: android-studio

I am having a serious block right now and cant figure out how to fix this error. When I try to open my NewTipActivity class the app unfortunately stops. I know where the error is located here is the logCat:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess
>   for a user with null id
>               at com.parse.ParseACL.setReadAccess(ParseACL.java:308)
>               at com.parse.ParseACL.getDefaultACL(ParseACL.java:61)
>               at com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:3385)
>               at com.parse.ParseObject.(ParseObject.java:181)
>               at com.parse.ParseObject.(ParseObject.java:127)
>               at com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.Tip.(Tip.java:17)
>               at com.holyapp.danshinn.wingman_etiquette.NewTipActivity.onCreate(NewTipActivity.java:20)

This is the NewTipActivity Class

```
public class NewTipActivity extends Activity {

    private Tip tip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       tip = new Tip();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //New Tip Fragment
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_tip);
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new NewTipFragment();
            manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    public Tip getCurrentTip() {
        return tip;

    }
```

}

I am very new to Parse so I know there is something within that that I am missing. I may not have declared my ParseUser GetAuthor() correctly.. Please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

i've similar error and i found the solution in:

[SetReadAccess error for new ParseObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881052/setreadaccess-error-for-new-parseobject)

When you setup Parse you have to add:

ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground(); // <--- This Line

Comment: ya it is similar issue which is indicated by miguel here