# parse Starter project crashes

Tags: android, parse-platform

i am new to parse and android app development.
im working with android studio on Mac OS X.
i have followed the parse quick start guide for a new project, i downloaded the Parse starter project and opened it in android studio.
i've followed the instructions, added the initialize line.
after that i compiled and ran the project, it works fine.
the problem im having is when im adding this code in the MainActivity onCreate function:

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.saveInBackground();
```

when i try to run the app after ive added the above code, my app crashes, it says in logcat this error:
can not setReadAcess for a user with null id.
here is the entire log from logcat:

```
> 05-02 22:18:42.006  18811-18811/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling
> CheckJNI (already on) 05-02 22:18:42.176 
> 18811-18845/com.parse.starter I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method
> android.database.Cursor.getNotificationUri, referenced from method
> com.parse.ParseSQLiteCursor.getNotificationUri 05-02 22:18:42.176 
> 18811-18845/com.parse.starter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve
> interface method 139: Landroid/database/Cursor;.getNotificationUri
> ()Landroid/net/Uri; 05-02 22:18:42.176  18811-18845/com.parse.starter
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 05-02 22:18:42.225 
> 18811-18811/com.parse.starter I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method
> android.app.ActivityManager.isLowRamDevice, referenced from method
> com.parse.ErrorReporter.getConstantDeviceData 05-02 22:18:42.225 
> 18811-18811/com.parse.starter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve
> virtual method 7: Landroid/app/ActivityManager;.isLowRamDevice ()Z
> 05-02 22:18:42.225  18811-18811/com.parse.starter D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c1 05-02 22:18:42.225 
> 18811-18811/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Crash reporting is
> enabled for com.parse.starter, initializing... 05-02 22:18:42.295 
> 18811-18818/com.parse.starter D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 285K, 3%
> free 12666K/12999K, paused 0ms+1ms 05-02 22:18:42.295 
> 18811-18811/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Looking for error
> files in /data/data/com.parse.starter/files/com.parse/cr/reports 05-02
> 22:18:42.295  18811-18811/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Looking
> for error files in
> /data/data/com.parse.starter/files/com.parse/cr/minidumps 05-02
> 22:18:42.365  18811-18811/com.parse.starter D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting
> down VM 05-02 22:18:42.365  18811-18811/com.parse.starter W/dalvikvm﹕
> threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3125180)
> 05-02 22:18:42.365  18811-18811/com.parse.starter E/CrashReporting﹕
> ParseCrashReporting caught a RuntimeException exception for
> com.parse.starter. Building report. 05-02 22:18:42.375 
> 18811-18811/com.parse.starter E/CrashReporting﹕ Handling exception for
> crash
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.parse.starter.ParseApplication:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user
> with null id
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3957)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id
>             at com.parse.ParseACL.setReadAccess(ParseACL.java:308)
>             at com.parse.ParseACL.getDefaultACL(ParseACL.java:61)
>             at com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:3385)
>             at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:181)
>             at com.parse.starter.ParseApplication.onCreate(ParseApplication.java:32)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-02 22:18:42.385  18811-18811/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕
> Generating report file for crash 05-02 22:18:42.538 
> 18811-18819/com.parse.starter I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to
> signal 3 05-02 22:18:42.538  18811-18819/com.parse.starter I/dalvikvm﹕
> Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 05-02 22:18:42.607 
> 18811-18818/com.parse.starter D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 318K, 4%
> free 12764K/13191K, paused 1ms+0ms 05-02 22:18:42.766 
> 18811-18811/com.parse.starter V/CrashReporting﹕ About to start
> ReportSenderWorker from #handleException 05-02 22:18:42.766 
> 18811-18872/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ #checkAndSendReports -
> start 05-02 22:18:42.766  18811-18872/com.parse.starter
> D/CrashReporting﹕ Looking for error files in
> /data/data/com.parse.starter/files/com.parse/cr/reports 05-02
> 22:18:42.766  18811-18872/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Loading
> file 1430594322387-IllegalArgumentException-1.stacktrace 05-02
> 22:18:42.796  18811-18872/com.parse.starter I/CrashReporting﹕ Sending
> file 1430594322387-IllegalArgumentException-1.stacktrace 05-02
> 22:18:42.796  18811-18872/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ Sending
> crash report to Parse... 05-02 22:18:42.806 
> 18811-18872/com.parse.starter D/CrashReporting﹕ #checkAndSendReports -
> finish 05-02 22:18:42.876  18811-18811/com.parse.starter
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.parse.starter.ParseApplication:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user
> with null id
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3957)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id
>             at com.parse.ParseACL.setReadAccess(ParseACL.java:308)
>             at com.parse.ParseACL.getDefaultACL(ParseACL.java:61)
>             at com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:3385)
>             at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:181)
>             at com.parse.starter.ParseApplication.onCreate(ParseApplication.java:32)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-02 22:18:43.026  18811-18819/com.parse.starter I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3:
> reacting to signal 3 05-02 22:18:43.026  18811-18819/com.parse.starter
> I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 05-02
> 22:18:43.455  18811-18819/com.parse.starter I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3:
> reacting to signal 3 05-02 22:18:43.455  18811-18819/com.parse.starter
> I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

there is no obvious reason why it will crash as i followed the exact steps in the quick start guide.
any idea why this is happening?

[here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart?app_id=lamed_sketch#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new) is a link for the quickstart guid

please help!
thanks.

Comment: Mind fixing the link? In any case, please include your code. Maybe you missed something.

Comment: What Android API version are you running against?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like permission problems. Did you save current user? Do you have user at all?

Did you try something like this:

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25881284/2466848)

Also. When you add these changes first remove app completely before testing.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer, it seems that the quickstart guide was not well explained, after some tinkering, i got it to work, i copied the entire sdk folder (the parse sdk i mean) to my project libs folder(instead of the whole content as i did previously), and then beside that folder i copied just the parse jar file, and then i had to go in android studio, navigate to the jar file, right click it and then add as library, and that did the trick... so thanks for all the replies!