# How to resolve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881052/setreadaccess-error-for-new-parseobject/25881284#25881284) and using accepted answer but then also I am getting this error. My application class code is:

```
//Enable Parse crash reports
ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID", "CLIENT_ID");

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
//defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

My Manifest file permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id

on `ParseObject photo = new ParseObject("Photo");`

Photo ParseClass has five fields of type string and one field of type pointer of _User type pointing to the User object. I create the new parse object and put the values in the corresponding fields and `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` in the pointer field and then pin in the Parse Local DataStore so that the objects can be accessed in offline mode.

Comment: I am not able to resolve this bug, please help!!

Comment: try to change your question and provide more code on your photo object as you got error with that object

Comment: @OlegOsipenko: Thanks for replying, I have edited the post and described Photo object and how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

`ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();` is asynchronous operation and when you're trying to put current user to Photo object it's not actually saved.

Try to add callback to your save method and then put your user when it's saved.

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (null == e) {
                photo.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                photo.pin();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: But `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();` is called in the application class and the pinning of the Photo object is done in the activity. So should I be call the `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();` in activity each time I want to pin the object?

Comment: Actually if you didn't do any changes to your user, it's not necessary to save it every time. Just check that user has id (null != ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()) - and it has it only if it was previously saved to parse.com, and if so, put user id to your object. Otherwise if there is no id then save user.